# jsp validation in same page

Tags: jsp

i want to validate the text box values in same jsp page and the output will be shown in the same jsp page .Is that possible

Comment: how can i do that please give suggestions

Comment: I would if you could provide more detail about what you are trying to accomplish.  Please post code samples and describe the problem.  :)  What have you tried so far?  Why hasn't it worked, etc.